# convert float number into time format?

Tags: python, html, time, odoo

Is there a way to convert float number to time format using html?
For example if you have number `8.5`, it would output `08:30`?

I have something like this:

```
<p><strong>${object.some_time}<strong></p> <!-- So this outputs that number -->
```

And I get this output:

**8.5**

But I would like to get this output:

**08:30**

**Update**
I tried this:

```
<p><strong>${object.some_time // 1}:${object.some_time % 1 * 60}<strong></p>
```

Then it outputs this:

**8.0:30.0**
If I put `int()` around either calculation, I don't get any output. So I think I can't for some reason convert types..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this way :

- cut the hours as you already do
- then do 60*minutes (here 0.5) and parseInt()

This should sove your probem

Comment: and to get it to a nice string: `my_string = '%02d:%02d' % (hours,minutes)`

Answer (score 0):

option 1: add a functional field which convert the float value to time string. Then use the functional field in your html.

option 2: create a method to convert the float to time string. Then call the function from your html code. 
option 3: i havent tried this.

${int(object.some_time // 1)}:${int(object.some_time % 1 * 60)}

Answer (score 0):

You can use following method to convert the float to time string.

```
function get_time_string(sometime) {
            currentHours =some_time // 1;
            currentMinutes = int(object.some_time % 1 * 60);
            if(currentHours <= 9){ 
                currentHours = "0" + currentHours;
                }
            if(currentMinutes <= 9) {
                 currentMinutes = "0" + currentMinutes;
                 }
            return currentHours+":"+currentMinutes;
        }
```